# Combining travis and ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, travis-ci

I have a github project that uses travis for continuous integration.  I would like to deploy my project on amazon ec2.  In order to simplify deployment, I would like the deployed system to have the same configuration as the test system.  Is this possible?

AFAICT, this requires two things: First, an ec2 preconfigured instance that matches the settings used by travis.  Does one exist?  And second, a way to execute `travis.yml` scripts from the command line.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for executing `.travis.yml` scripts from the command line, if I were you I would instead take it the other way around and replace your `.travis.yml` script with something like this:

```yaml
language: bleh

etc etc...

install:
  - ./travis-scripts/install.sh

before_script:
  - ./travis-scripts/before_script.sh

script:
  - ./travis-scripts/script.sh
```

Of course, you will still have to write a script for installing whatever language versions, Travis plugins etc you need on your Amazon EC2 instance.

As for an Amazon EC2 instance that matches Travis VMs, I don't know about that because I'm not so familiar with Amazon AWS, but I can tell you that Travis VMs are based on Ubuntu 12.04, and there is a lot more specific information in the page about [The Build Environment](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/).

Answer (score 0):

So you want something on a EC2 instance that can read your .travis.yml file and configure it in the same way that travis does when it tests?

I think that's a pretty long shot for a relatively simple problem like this. Travis is an integration and testing platform that uses a lot of other systems (like chef and docker) to do what it does with the .yml files. To use this system to run a single app sounds a bit overkill.

I would recommend using chef (or similar like puppet) to configure your production environment and deploy your app.

You could have one chef recipe that configures the production environment (DB's, configuration files, install stuff, etc...) and another that deploys, configures and starts your app. When you want to make changes to the production environment, you make changes to these files. They can easily be bundled with the project.